# KeyConditionExpression takes in invalid input and does not throw exception

Tags: python-3.x, error-handling, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm new to DynamoDB and trying to power through its documentation, as well as boto3
I have written some code that is supposed to query a few tables for different parameters and do some calculation. It works, however I have not yet implemented error handling.
What I noticed, is when I pass through an invalid customerName in .eq(customerName), it does not throw any related errors and just proceeds to further calculations, which would obviously fail. 
However, if I change Key from 'CustomerName' to something random, it would detect that.
How do I check that the customerName entered through the input does exist, and if not, throw an error? This try-except doesn't catch it. I came across attribute_not_exists that logically similar to what I'm trying to achieve, but it doesn't take keys.

```
    try:
        response = table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('customerName').eq(customerName),
            ProjectionExpression='price',
            )

            # some code

    except ClientError as err:
        logger.info(f"The customer {customerName} doesn't exist: {err}")
        sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: How do you check the customername is not exist before you query about that? Why the costomername is wrong if it does not exist? That is not wrong. If you have made some index of the column values then you might check the existence of the value more faster but before the query, you cannot know it exists or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying with an invalid key name in the key condition expression throws an exception because it's a nonsense query.

Querying for a nonexistent key value isn't an error -- that's true of essentially any database you are likely to encounter.    The database has nothing upon which to base a conclusion that the value is "wrong" because that isn't exactly a meaningful concept with regard to a value that simply isn't found.

`response['Items']` contains the set of matching items.  If no records are found, it has no items.  You should be checking for this condition, if no records found is something you consider to be unexpected.